# Как работать с указателем на указатель в си?

Tags: c, указатели

Смоделирую ситуацию, у меня есть связный список на языке си. Я хочу сделать функцию поиска(неважно, что это неправильнО), которая будет возвращать указатель на указатель на последний неинициализированный элемент списка. Вот зачем это нужно: чтоб добавить элемент в список нужно проинициализировать указатель на next последнего его элемента списка`current->next = malloc(sizeof(list_node)).Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтоб эта функция поиска вернула указатель на этот самый указатель next, чтоб его можно было проинициализировать в отрыве от последнего элемента списка, в котором этот указатель и находится. Это просто пример, не самый лучшей.

Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь проинициализировать указатель, который вернула мне функция(которая возвразает указатель на указатель), к примеру так *point = malloc(..), я получаю ошибку, потому что разыминовываю ничего... Почему так? Я же разыминовываю указатель на указатель, значит результатом разыминования должен быть указатель на неинициализированную область памяти.

Comment: Где тут разыменование? Где указатель на указатель?

Comment: @MBo, point - это указатель на указатель, чтоб получить указатель, на который он указывает я его разменовываю *point, но получаю ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Ты получаешь ошибку из-за того,что ты не можешь присвоить void* указателю любого другого типа.Для корректного использования функции динамического выделения памяти нужно явно приводить результат вызова функции к нужному вам типу